# PHP contact form submission

Tags: php, forms, email

I came across the “str_replace” and figured I could use that to just eliminate the underscores. 
I’ve tried a dozen times and I can’t get it to work. Could you tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Output with underscore in Email

```
Mortgage_Company :
XYZ Comp
Mcstreet :
77 Main Road
```

page form

```
<h1>Mortgage Company Information</h1>
<div><span class='error'><?php echo $formproc->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='Mortgage_Company'>Company Name* </label>
    <input type='text' name='Mortgage_Company' id='Mortgage_Company' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('Mortgage_Company') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_Mortgage_Company_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='mcstreet' >Company Street Address* </label>
    <input type='text' name='mcstreet' id='mcstreet' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('mcstreet') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_mcstreet_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
```

section of array

```
$ret_str='';
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        {
            if(!$this->IsInternalVariable($key))
            {
                $value = htmlentities($value,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
                $value = nl2br($value);
                $key = ucfirst($key);
                // str_replace
                $key = str_replace("_"," ",$key);
                $ret_str .= "<div class='label'>$key :</div><div class='value'>$value </div>\n";

            }
        }
```

Comment: FYI: variable interpolation (eg. `$name` being substituted for the string contained within the `$name` variable) only happens on double quoted strings in PHP. Your 2nd string is single quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use variables in a string and \n you need to use double quotes, like:

```
$retstr ="Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Association: $association \n Street: $street \n E-mail: $email";
```

Try it this way.

Comment: If it was useful it would be appreciated if you mark it as answer by clicking on the green checkmark on the left. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Only now the data for $name, $email_address, etc. isn’t showing up in the email. 

I think the php file was using an array of some kind. Is there a way around this? 

I can post the entire php file script.

Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Yeah I think you should post the full script if you want more help. Maybe another question and you can send me the link.

Comment: I re-edited the question the question above to include the full code.
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ok, that's a lot of code, in the first opportunity I have I'll check it out.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look over the code?

Comment: Sorry I've had a lot of work, I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry, I just checked the file, if you still have that issue with the `$email`, maybe you should check your POST request, because the only assignment on the code is `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: I revised the code to and updated the POST requests. The values are still missing after submitting a complete form.

Comment: Ok, are the names in the form right?

Comment: I checked twice. All the names are right.

Comment: Ok then the only option you hace is to debug the variable to ser where is the mistake.

Comment: Hi again,
I’ve been having the worst luck getting this to work. 
I came across the “str_replace” and figured I could use that to just eliminate the underscores. 
I’ve tried a dozen times and I can’t get it to work. Could you tell me what I’m doing wrong?
I’ve updated the code above to show a sample.
Thanks again.